# nginx root file - index.php

Tags: nginx, settings

i'm setting up an webserver based on nginx and php-fpm. All is ok but my domain opens just directory on www.domain.com/ - it should open index.php as i got this in my config:

```
location / {
    autoindex  on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

It should open index.php when typing www.domain.com - but it dont. How i can set root file - index.php index.html index.htm?

Answer (score 0):

Your `server` block needs to contain the `index` directive.

```
server {
    index index.php;
```